# setTitleTextAttributes not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uifont

Hello in I've been facing this weird bug where the app only works on iPhone 6.

so in one of my methods I have

```
- (void)dummy {
   UIFont *titleFont = [HTFont thinFontOfSize:20];
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ 
   NSFontAttributeName:titleFont }];
}
```

**If I comment that out, the app works on iPhone 4s**

I am assuming it is something wrong with the `HTFont` file but I can't seem to figure it out.

**HTFont.m**

```
#define IS_IPAD   (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

#define SCREEN_WIDTH  CGRectGetWidth([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds])
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds])

#define IS_IPHONE4  (IS_IPHONE && MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE5  (IS_IPHONE && MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE6  (IS_IPHONE && MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE6P (IS_IPHONE && MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) == 736.0)

static NSString * const kFontName = @"SourceSansPro-Regular";
static NSString * const kThinName = @"SourceSansPro-Light";

@implementation HTFont

+ (UIFont *)fontOfSize:(CGFloat)size {

    return [UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:[HTFont     adjustedFontSizeForScreen:size]];
}

+ (UIFont *)thinFontOfSize:(CGFloat)size {

    return [UIFont fontWithName:kThinName size:[HTFont     adjustedFontSizeForScreen:size]];
}

+ (CGFloat)adjustedFontSizeForScreen:(CGFloat)size {

    if (IS_IPHONE5) {

       return size;

    } else if (IS_IPHONE6) {

        return size * 1.1;

    } else if (IS_IPHONE6P) {

       return size * 1.2;

    } else {

        return size * 0.9;
    }
}
```

What could be causing the error?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception    
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary    
initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from   
objects[1]'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Looks like the font isn't valid and is returning `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy but why would it work on iPhone 6?

Comment: Is that a custom font provided by your app or is it a newer app not found on your older device?

Comment: @rmaddy it's a font I imported SourceSansPro-Regular

Comment: @PictureMeAndYou I'm like 99% sure you didn't add the font correctly and it's acting like a weird bug.

Comment: @KRUKUSA just readded the fonts. Seems like that was the problem all along... Weird how it worked for iPhone 6 only